# Повышающее преобразование динамического массива указателей на объекты наследников в базовый тип

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь разобраться, как передать в функцию, которая принимает динамический массив указателей на объекты **базового** класса, динамический массив указателей на объекты **родительского** класса. Я написал простой код, и не понимаю, почему он не работает. Передача указателя на объект родительского класса выполняется без проблем, то есть повышающее преобразование отрабатывает так, как нужно. Возможно, я не совсем правильно понимаю, как передавать, хотелось бы объяснений и/или исправлений. Спасибо.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void run() override
    {

    }
};

void test(A** a, size_t s) // приём динамического массива указателей на объекты базового класса
{
    for (size_t i(0); i < s; ++i)
        (*(a + i))->run();
}

void test2(A* a) // приём указателя на объект базового класса
{
    a->run();
}

int main()
{
    B** a = new B * [10]; // создаем динамический массив указателей на объекты родительского класса
    B* b = new B; // создаем указатель на объект родительского класса
    test(a, 10); // попытка передать динамический массив указателей на объекты родительского класса: ERROR
    test2(b); // передача указателя на объект родительского класса: ОК
    return 0;
}
```

Интересуюсь в целях обучения.

Comment: Зачем вам двойной указатель? Вы в B** a = new B * [10]; не создаёте объекты, а создаёте 10 указателей на B*, которые никуда не указывают.

Comment: @КириллМалышев в каком плане, я не совсем понял вопрос. Где именно? Массив указателей на объекты или аргумент функции?

Comment: Создавайте массив объектов так: B *a = new B[10];

Comment: @КириллМалышев понял Вас. В целях обучения спрашиваю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что такое преобразование указателя на один класс в указатель на другой класс (то же верно и для ссылок) возможно, когда эти классы находятся в одной иерархии. В примере `B` наследует от `A`, соответственно указатель на `B` можно преобразовать в указатель на `A`, причем в таком простом случае даже не надо будет модифицировать значение адреса. А вот типы `B *` и `A *` уже не родственные, и в общем случае так просто одно из другого не получить.

Проиллюстрирую на более наглядном примере:

```
struct A { float f; };
struct B { int i; };
struct D: B, A { };
```

Тут `D` наследует от `A`. Имея `D *` можно получить `A *` просто увеличив адрес на 4 байта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что же произойдет, когда у вас массив `D *`? Имея указатель на первый элемент этого массива `D * *` никакими преобразованиями адреса из него не удастся получить `A * *`. Для этого потребуется выделять новый массив указателей `A *` и конвертировать каждый из указателей `D *` из исходного массива.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже в простой ситуации, как в вашем примере, когда адреса указателей совпадают, от добавления перенаправления возникает еще один эффект, препятствующий их преобразованию:

```
class X: public A {}; // еще один класс
...
void testX(A** p_a)
{
    // попытка присвоить X * указателю А * вполне правомерна
    p_a[0] = new X{}; // ОК
}

int main()
{
    B** p_b = new B * [10];
    // попытка присвоить X * указателю B * очевидно ошибочна
    p_b[0] = new X{}; // ERROR
    // если бы это работало, то в массиве указателей B * легко мог бы оказаться X *
    testX(p_b);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все понятно!

Comment: @Range То было еще не все...

Comment: уже активно читаю продолжение